# Why mutable strings can cause security issue?

Tags: java, string, immutability

I saw an answer from another [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195099/why-is-string-immutable-in-java):

String has been widely used as parameter for many java classes e.g. for opening network connection , for opening database connection, opening files . If String is not immutable, this would lead to serious security threat .

I think checking the string before use it would solve the problem. Why is it a reason that string is designed to be immutable?

Can anyone give me a concrete code example?

Comment: "I think checking the string before use it would solve the problem" Unless you're explicitly using some sort of lock, no.

Comment: If implemented improperly, what stops an offender from changing your check's reference?

Comment: There is many reason that string is designed to be immutable, understand the immutable like that: *when a class is independent and completely concrete in nature.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it's easier to write and review sensitive code when values don't change, because
there are fewer interleavings of operations that might affect the result.

Imagine code like

```
void doSomethingImportant(String name) {
  if (!isAlphaNumeric(name)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
  Object o = lookupThingy(name);
  // No chance of SQL-Injection because name is alpha-numeric.
  connection.executeStatement("INSERT INTO MyTable (column) VALUES ('" + name + "')");
}
```

The code does some checks to prevent an escalation of authority, but this only holds if `isAlphaNumeric(name)` is true when the argument to `executeStatement` is called.

If the first two statements were re-ordered then this would not be a problem, so the insecurity arises, in-part, from a bad interleaving.  But other code might call this function and assume that `name` is not changed by it, so might have to perform and re-perform validity checks.

If `String` is not immutable, then it might have been changed by `lookupThingy`.  To be sure the security check works, there is a much larger amount of code that has to perform correctly for this code to be secure against SQL injection.

Not only is the amount of code that has to perform correctly larger, but a maintainer who makes local changes to one function might affect the security of other functions far-away.  Non-local effects make code-maintenance hard.  Maintaining security properties is always dicey since security vulnerabilities are rarely obvious, so mutability can lead to degradation of security over time.

---

> Why is it a reason that string is designed to be immutable?

This is separate from why it is bad security-wise.

It is widely believed that programs written in languages with readily-available immutable string types do fewer unnecessary buffer copies than ones that do not.  Unnecessary buffer copies eat up memory, cause GC churn, and can cause simple operations on large inputs to perform much worse than on small inputs.

It is also widely believed that it is easier to write correct programs when using immutable strings, because you are unlikely to fail to defensively copy a buffer.

Comment: Or worse, perhaps the String is visible to another thread, which could then change its value between the integrity check and the use -- even without a clear intervening call!

Answer (score 2):

It's the oldest security spoof in the book:  Present some parm to the operating system, have it validate the parm, then update the parm while the OS is referring to the parm, so it will do things different from what it verified.

This was used to break IBM OS/360 back in the 60s:  To request disk I/O you would pass the OS a "channel program" that contained the disk address and memory address and other stuff.  The OS would check that the disk and memory addresses were locations to which you were authorized, then it would pass that "channel program" along to the I/O channel hardware to be executed, without making a local copy first.  It was not hard to time things so that you'd modify the channel program after it was checked but before the I/O channel hardware executed it, allowing access to unauthorized disk and memory.

(Keep in mind that in this timeframe memory was very precious, so not copying the channel program saved a non-trivial amount of memory.  But this loophole was fairly quickly closed once the way to exploit it became fairly well known.)

(Of course, one must question whether *any* Objective-C program can be considered "secure" from other code running in the same process.  The "duck typing" nature of Objective-C makes true security improbable at best.  Using immutable strings is more of a protection against accidental modification than against malicious modification.)

Answer (score 1):

The post you linked to further links to this post, where the issue is explained in more detail:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190699/when-and-why-would-we-use-immutable-pointers/190913#190913